# Reading from file to database prolog

Tags: database, file, prolog

**Hello everyone**

I have problem with part of my project for studies. 
My task is to write a program in prolog that can tell you what illnes do you have based on input from user. Data base must be read from a file which format is up to me.

**Construction:**

I decide to have 2 dynamic rules;

```
:- dynamic (illness/2).
:- dynamic (symptoms/4).
```

where:

```
illnes(name_of_illness, symptoms(symptom1, symptom2, symptom3, symptom4)
```

File: example.txt:

```
flu,cough,fever,head_acke, runny_nose.
measles, rash, fever, sore_throat, inflamed_eyes.
```

**Problem:**

My major problem is to format this data to use asserta predicat, I tried many ways but it didn't work.

**Thank you**

Comment: Your spelling and formatting are improving! Also, it is not necessary to declare `symptoms/4` as it isn't a dynamic rule, it's just a structure inside `illness/2`.

Comment: Given that, as you wrote, "Data base must be read from a file *which format is up to me*", why not make the file a Prolog file and save yourself a lot of trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, per [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54154124/deleting-char-from-atomic-list-asserta-prolog), I think you can parse these strings with `split_string/4`, your problem is that the result of that is not atoms, and then you need to build the structure properly. This I think is the piece you're missing:

```
?- split_string("this,that,the,other,thing", ",", " ", X), 
   maplist(atom_string, [Condition,Sym1,Sym2,Sym3,Sym4], X), 
   Result = illness(Condition, symptoms(Sym1,Sym2,Sym3,Sym4)).
X = ["this", "that", "the", "other", "thing"],
Condition = this,
Sym1 = that,
Sym2 = the,
Sym3 = other,
Sym4 = thing,
Result = illness(this, symptoms(that, the, other, thing)).
```

If you then simply `asserta(Result)` you have added the right thing to the database.

If you have a variable number of symptoms, you should keep it a list in there instead, and that would simplify your processing greatly (and probably our downstream code, as doing anything four times in a row is a bit repetitive):

```
?- split_string("this,that,the,other,thing", ",", " ", X), 
   maplist(atom_string, [Condition|Symptoms], X), 
   Result = illness(Condition, symptoms(Symptoms)).
X = ["this", "that", "the", "other", "thing"],
Condition = this,
Symptoms = [that, the, other, thing],
Result = illness(this, symptoms([that, the, other, thing])).
```

Comment: Thank you! You solved my problem in 100% procent! My hero

Comment: Glad to help! Please accept the answer if it solves your problem.